# snipMate.vim error only when opening index.html files

Tags: vim, snipmate

I keep getting this error

```
"index.html" 20L, 382C
Warning in snipMate.vim: Snippet section is already defined. 
See :h multi_snip for help on snippets with multiple matches.
```

Whenever I open an `index.html` file in vim. Only index.html for whatever reason : /

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your `snippets` folder, there must be a `html.snippet` file. Inside, search for a snippet called `section`, it's duplicated. Remove one of the duplicates and you probably will be good to go.

Comment: You found the duplicate? The warning disappeared?